# 'The file name must end with .xml' when i try to read the value from text file(.txt) inside the assets folder

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I'm trying to read the value from the text file(.txt), which is inside the `assets` folder, when I try to rebuild the project, I'm getting this error, how to solve this?

```
The file name must end with .xml
```

this is the java code, I'm trying to read the value from the text file,

```
         try {

            InputStream is=getAssets().open("english.text");
            int size=is.available();

            byte[] buffer=new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            line=new String(buffer);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `assets/` directory in the wrong place. It needs to directly under `main/`, as a peer of `java/` and `res/`.

Comment: thanks great, it's works, i will accept this answer ❤️